# How to list all object paths under a dbus service, in C with gio/glib?

Tags: c, glib

A follow up to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203410/how-to-list-all-object-paths-under-a-dbus-service) but I'd like to do it in C, not python, with glib-2.0/gio-2.0. I've really been having a hard time finding an example of this, in C, and the documentation is hard to read for a new comer as it's just a giant api list.

Comment: While I appreciate the move I already asked this on SO and it was closed prior so I guess there is just so good place to ask this :(

Comment: That is because you're asking a question that implies searching and recommending a library instead of solving an error in your code.  Search Google and you should quite easily find relevant links.  Then try to use the provided tools and post a more precise question.

Comment: I'm not asking to recommend a library? I specify the gio library which is pretty standard for GNOME and I want to know if there is an API within it to preform a certain task. I have searched a ton on google and as an experience linux user I cannot find helpful examples or make sense of the API document, in the context of this question. My question is code related but  posting every API that doesn't work from the GNOME dev site doesn't have any value add to getting the API I'm looking for or if it even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client-side DBus calls, you can use a **[GDbusProxy](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/GDBusProxy.html)** object in glib.
Using org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable as in the original question:

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GError *error;
  GDBusProxyFlags flags;
  GDBusProxy *proxy;
  gpointer data;

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  error = NULL;
  proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_for_bus_sync (G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM
                                     flags,
                                     NULL, /* GDBusInterfaceInfo */
                                     name, /* your service name */
                                     object_path, /* your root object */
                                   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable",
                                     NULL, /* GCancellable */
                                     &error);
g_dbus_proxy_call(proxy,
                 "Introspect", NULL,
                  G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                 -1, NULL,
                  (GAsyncReadyCallback) some_callback,
                  &data);
```

Then you can define the function some_callback to  handle the xml containing the objects.